# Is it fine for CPU Cooler mounting backplate washers to touch motherboard traces?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cpu-cooler

I have made a new build with an Intel core i7 13700k, an Asus Prime z790 motherboard and a DeepCool AK620 cooler. What I'm wondering is if the washers of the backplate of the CPU cooler are supposed to touch directly on the back of the motherboard on top of the traces that run along the motherboard.

I've seen some CPU coolers that have very small rubber washers between the cpu backplate and the motherboard (to avoid touching the traces I suppose), but in my case the washers are made of hard plastic. The pc turns on and works well.

The backplate im using is this one https://imgur.com/pt6JBs3

I've seen other cpu cooler manufacturers, like noctua, are using slimmer touch points, I suppose it's to avoid touching the motherboard traces, but ,also from noctua, I've seen backplates with washers made of hard plastic that are bigger.

[Video from Noctua with big hard plastic washers that I think will touch the motherboard traces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--DsrNCv2Zo)

[Video from Noctua with small washers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ioaon-11z24)

Is it ok for cpu backplate washers to sit on top of motherboard traces? Do I risk damaging the motherboard?

I don't know if I'm overthinking this too much, I've not found any other info online about this topic. Thanks for reading.